# Cut and Paste in .NET Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, chinese-locale

I have a (partly) Chinese .NET application (and I don't know any Chinese). So I Would like to translate some prompts (I don't want to change the program, just understand the prompts) via Google Translate.

Is there a way to cut & paste the text in a .NET Windows Form label (it is only a few characters, but I don't know how to type them in Chinese)?

I do even have the source for the application, but I can't find the Chinese strings in them (because the source is full of Chinese (in fields, comments, ...) and I can't cut & paste into the search field).

Any idea?

Comment: Just use the built-in support for localization.  Set the form's Localizable to True.  Pick the right kind of Chinese from the Language dropdown.  Select the Label and paste the Text property value.  Google Translate is not exactly a localization authority of course.

Comment: How do I set the form to Localizable? Google Translate is just a tool to get a rough idea about the dialog contents.

Comment: Set the form's Localizable *property* to True.  In the Properties window, you can't miss it.

Answer (score 0):

To inspect and modify the properties of WinForms controls at runtime, you can use a tool like [Hawkeye](http://hawkeye.codeplex.com/). When the application is running, just point Hawkeye's crosshair to a label in Chinese and copy the value of its Text property which will show up in Hawkeye's property grid.

Update: depending on the version of .NET the target application is using, download either N2 or N4 version of Hawkeye from the [download page](http://hawkeye.codeplex.com/releases/view/58898).

Comment: Hawkeye does not work for me. I can see control information when I drag the crosshair over the Hawkeye window, but I see no information, when I drag (and drop it) over the application. Just a message that the window is from a different process and I should release it (whatever that means).

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it: you probably used the .NET 2 version of Hawkeye and your application is written in .NET 4. In that case, try using the N4 version from the download page: http://hawkeye.codeplex.com/releases/view/58898

Comment: I really used N2. But things don't change with N4.